# Run components with .Net Core 2.2 and .Net Core 3.0 in parallel

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I am building a new component, and I am so excited to use .Net Core 3.0. However, we should plan for the migration of other components which are built with .Net Core 2.2 or 2.1. so if I build with 3.0 I need to run it with others which are 2.1 and 2.2
I am searching around to figure out if there is something that I should know beforehand regarding running this new component .Net Core 3.0 with others which are .Net Core 2.2 or 2.1.
Does anyone have a suggestion/concern/idea regarding this?

Comment: What is the question? How to run different runtimes side-by-side? Or how to create components that are compatible with different runtimes?

Comment: Different runtimes *can* run side-by-side. If you want to produce a single component that's usable by both runtimes with minimal effort target .NET Standard 2.0, not specific runtimes. Otherwise you can specify multiple runtimes with the `TargetFrameworks` tag in csproj and get different binaries for different runtimes.

Comment: You can easily run .NET Core apps side-by-side. Framework-dependent .NET Core apps roll forward as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection). For self-contained deployments, the runtime version is selected when you publish the app and not when you run it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the question is about running two different but dependent components however they have been built with different.net core version, 3.0 and 2.2.

Comment: @mm8 very good points about deployment. my focus was more on this nullable.

Comment: @mm8 I mean using c# 8 which includes nullable

Comment: @ShrnPrmshr: I don't understand what your issue is. You don't mention anything about C#8 in your question...? It's about different version of .NET Core.

Comment: @mm8 that is a good point. maybe I needed to mention that in the question. Yes I want to use the C# 8 with .net core 3.0 which is new to our platform

Comment: @ShrnPrmshr: What's stopping you from doing this?

Comment: @mm8 nothing stopping me. I am just wondering if I need to know and think about something beforehand